# 20.04 how to downgrade kernel from 5.4.0-56-generic to 5.4.0-55.61

Tags: kernel, amd-graphics, downgrade

The 5.4.0-56 does not like AMD graphic driver. Based on https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45 I need to downgrade to 5.4.0-51 to install the graphic card's driver
How can I downgrade the kernel?

Comment: If you run `dpkg --list | grep linux-image | grep ^ii` it should show you all the kernels currently installed on your system.  It is easiest to reboot then choose Advanced Options in grub and boot to an older kernel, then remove the newer kernel.  Also, `linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic` just barely got released so the newest one might work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I could downgrade to a lower version 5.4.0-53 and installing the AMD driver 20.45. But it seems the kernel 5.4.0-58 has its own problem. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299450/login-fails-after-upgrade-of-ubuntu-20-04-kernel-and-headers

Comment: Interesting.  I upgraded both of my systems here in my den to 5.4.0-58 and neither experienced login loops or login issues for that matter.  Also, I have one with a NVIDIA card and the other with an AMD and both installed and booted fine as well.